# Possible causes for error while saving file in python while running on nginx?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a .py script that saves a base64 file to a png file

```
# SAVE BASE64 STRING TO PNG IMAGE
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
filename = "/user_score/"+self.user.username+timestr+".png"
saved_file = MEDIA_ROOT+"/"+filename
fh = open(saved_file, "wb")
fh.write(imgbase64.decode('base64'))
fh.close()
```

This is being called through an AJAX function to an URL like this one

```
http://example-domain.com/score/save_image/?img=iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA4QAAAJYCAYAAAA6xSjbAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3b0ZYUN7KGUfz%2BD92z2mMYzDRUZkkKhfLf59ZFSrFDXHyLM399fHx8fPN%2FBAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAn8JcgjNu5gQkQIECAAAECBAgQIPC3gCD0EAgQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIAAAQIECBAgECogCEMXb2wCBAgQIECAAAECBAgIQm%2BAAAECBAgQIECAAAECoQKCMHTxxiZAgAABAgQIECBAgIAg9AYIECBAgAABAgQIECAQKiAIQxdvbAIECBAgQIAAAQIECAhCb4AAAQIECBAgQIAAAQKhAoIwdPHGJkCAAAECBAgQIECAgCD0BggQIECAAAECBAgQIBAqIAhDF29sAgQIECBAgAABAgQICEJvgAABAgQIECBAgAABAqECgjB08cYmQIAAAQIECBAgQICAIPQGCBAgQIDAAoG%2F%2FvprwVe%2Fffv4%2BFjyXR8lQIAAgUwBQZi5d1MTIECAwGSBVQH4u2sKw8kL9DkCBAiECgjC0MUbmwABAgTGBaojUByO78wXCBAgQODfAoLQiyBAgAABAjcFuoTgr9f2r4Y3F%2BnnBAgQIPBNEHoEBAgQIEDgokDXEPz5%2BqLw4jL9jAABAgT%2BFhCEHgIBAgQIPF7gM%2BRGQumEEPSvhY9%2FxgYkQIDAEgFBuITVRwkQIEBgtsBolL0ThKNnzjZ453vvzP3OOf4MAQIECJwpIAjP3JtbEyBAIE5gNM7uhNHoWR2Xc2f%2Bjvd3JwIECBBYIyAI17j6KgECBAhMFhiNtCtBNHrG5JGnf%2B6KwfRDfZAAAQIEWgsIwtbrcTkCBAgQ%2BC4wGmt%2FiqHRb5%2B0JVF40rbclQABAusFBOF6YycQIECAwASB0Wj7KoRGvzlhrG2fEIbb6B1MgACBVgKCsNU6XIYAAQIEficwGm8%2FB9Dot562JXH4tI2ahwABAtcFBOF1K78kQIAAgY0CoxH3PXpGv7ORYPnRwnA5sQMIECDQTkAQtluJCxEgQIDAVwJCru5dCMM6aycRIEBgt4Ag3L0B5xMgQIDAJQFBeIlp6o%2BE4VROHyNAgEBLAUHYci0uRYAAAQK%2FCgjCPW9CFO5xdyoBAgSqBARhlbRzCBAgQGBI4OQgHImqDnOP3H9o6f4wAQIECCwXEITLiR1AgAABAjMEOoTRnTlWRNROgxXz3PH0WwIECBBYIyAI17j6KgECBAhMFtgZQ1dHqYimnQ4V81219jsCBAgQmCMgCOc4%2BgoBAgQILBbYGUKvRtsRSrs8dsz6yt9%2FJ0CAAIH3BQTh%2B3b%2BJAECBAgUCuwKoD%2BN2CGOdrh0mLvw6TmKAAECjxYQhI9er%2BEIECDwHIEd4fM7vY5BVO3T0eA5r90kBAgQqBMQhHXWTiJAgACBAYHq4Pnqqt0jqNKou8XAU%2FNHCRAgECUgCKPWbVgCBAicK1AZO78qnRQ%2FlU4nuZz78t2cAAECawUE4VpfXydAgACBSQKVofP9yicHT4XXyT6TnqXPECBA4HgBQXj8Cg1AgACBDIGKwPlZ8kmxs9LuSU4Zf5NMSYAAgX8LCEIvggABAgSOEFgZNU8NwV8Xu8JQEB7x18clCRAg8FsBQehxECBAgMARAiti5tfBU%2BJmtmWK2xF%2FUVySAAECNwUE4U0wPydAgACBPQKzIyY1Br%2FPPdNTEO75O%2BFUAgQIzBAQhDMUfYMAAQIElgvMDJj0GPycf7anKFz%2BV8ABBAgQWCIgCJew%2BigBAgQIzBaYHTDf75ccMjNNkx1nv3XfI0CAQKWAIKzUdhYBAgQIvC0wM17E4P%2FWMMtVEL79tP1BAgQIbBUQhFv5HU6AAAECVwVmhYsY%2FH%2FxWbai8Opr9jsCBAj0ERCEfXbhJgQIECDwB4FZ0SIIv0ae4SsI%2FRUmQIDAeQKC8LyduTEBAgQiBWYEixj8%2FdOZ4SsII%2F9qGpoAgcMFBOHhC3R9AgQIpAjMCBZBKAhT%2Fr6YkwABAlcFBOFVKb8jQIAAga0CgnA9%2F6ixfyFcvyMnECBAYLaAIJwt6nsECBAgsERgNFb86%2BDrtcwwFoWvnf2CAAECnQQEYadtuAsBAgQI%2FFZgRqx8flyw%2FP6RzTDm6y8xAQIEzhIQhGfty20JECAQKzAjVgThn58P49i%2FXgYnQCBYQBAGL9%2FoBAgQOElArNRsa4azfyWs2ZVTCBAgMENAEM5Q9A0CBAgQWC4wGiqfkfL5DbGy%2Fl8JGS%2F%2F6%2BAAAgQITBMQhNMofYgAAQIEVgrMCMKV93vKt0edPx0E4VNegzkIEEgQEIQJWzYjAQIEHiAwGioi5fojYH3dyi8JECBwuoAgPH2D7k%2BAAIEQAZFSt2jWddZOIkCAwG4BQbh7A84nQIAAgUsCIuUS05QfjVp%2FXsK%2FyE5ZhY8QIEBguYAgXE7sAAIECBCYITAaKQLl%2BhZGrQXhdWu%2FJECAwG4BQbh7A84nQIAAgUsCo5EiCC8x%2F%2F2jUWtBeN3aLwkQILBbQBDu3oDzCRAgQOCSwGikCMJLzILwOpNfEiBA4BECgvARazQEAQIEni8gCGt3zLvW22kECBDYJSAId8k7lwABAgRuCQiUW1zDP%2BY9TOgDBAgQOEJAEB6xJpckQIAAAYFS%2BwZ413o7jQABArsEBOEueecSIECAwC0BgXKLa%2FjHvIcJfYAAAQJHCAjCI9bkkgQIECAgUGrfAO9ab6cRIEBgl4Ag3CXvXAIECBC4JSBQbnEN%2F5j3MKEPECBA4AgBQXjEmlySAAECBARK7RvgXevtNAIECOwSEIS75J1LgAABArcEBMotruEf8x4m9AECBAgcISAIj1iTSxIgQICAQKl9A7xrvZ1GgACBXQKCcJe8cwkQIEDgloBAucU1%2FGPew4Q%2BQIAAgSMEBOERa3JJAgQIEBAotW%2BAd6230wgQILBLQBDukncuAQIECNwSECi3uIZ%2FzHuY0AcIECBwhIAgPGJNLkmAAAECAqX2DfCu9XYaAQIEdgkIwl3yziVAgACBWwIC5RbX8I95DxP6AAECBI4QEIRHrMklCRAgQECg1L4B3rXeTiNAgMAuAUG4S965BAgQIHBLQKDc4hr%2BMe9hQh8gQIDAEQKC8Ig1uSQBAgQICJTaN8C71ttpBAgQ2CUgCHfJO5cAAQIEbgkIlFtcwz%2FmPUzoAwQIEDhCQBAesSaXJECAAAGBUvsGeNd6O40AAQK7BAThLnnnEiBAgMAtAYFyi2v4x7yHCX2AAAECRwgIwiPW5JIECBAgIFBq3wDvWm%2BnESBAYJeAINwl71wCBAgQuCUgUG5xDf%2BY9zChDxAgQOAIAUF4xJpckgABAgQESu0b4F3r7TQCBAjsEhCEu%2BSdS4AAAQK3BATKLa7hH%2FMeJvQBAgQIHCEgCI9Yk0sSIECAgECpfQO8a72dRoAAgV0CgnCXvHMJECBA4JaAQLnFNfxj3sOEPkCAAIEjBAThEWtySQIECBAQKLVvgHett9MIECCwS0AQ7pJ3LgECBAjcEhAot7iGf8x7mNAHCBAgcISAIDxiTS5JgAABAgKl9g3wrvV2GgECBHYJCMJd8s4lQIAAgVsCAuUW1%2FCPeQ8T%2BgABAgSOEBCER6zJJQkQIEBAoNS%2BAd613k4jQIDALgFBuEveuQQIECBwS0Cg3OIa%2FjHvYUIfIECAwBECgvCINbkkAQIECAiUujcwav1504%2BPj7oLO4kAAQIE3hYQhG%2FT%2BYMECBAgUCkwGikC5dq2Rp2%2Fn8L7mrdfESBAYLeAINy9AecTIECAwCWB0VARKK%2BZR41%2FPoH3a2%2B%2FIECAQAcBQdhhC%2B5AgAABAi8FRmNFoLwk%2FjZq7F8HXxv7BQECBLoJCMJuG3EfAgQIEPhSYDRWBOGfH9aor38d9BeXAAECZwoIwjP35tYECBCIExgNFkH4%2Byczavvrl1nH%2FfU0MAECBwsIwoOX5%2BoECBBIEhiNFpEiCJP%2BvpiVAAECVwUE4VUpvyNAgACBrQKCcD7%2FqOlXNxLe8%2FfkiwQIEFgpIAhX6vo2AQIECEwTGI0XofLfVYw6vloo51dC%2FjsBAgR6CQjCXvtwGwIECBD4jcBoyKSHyqjflYeZbnzFyG8IECDQTUAQdtuI%2BxAgQIDAlwKjQZMcK6N2V55ksu8VH78hQIBAVwFB2HUz7kWAAAEC%2FxIYjZrUYBl1u%2FIMU22v2PgNAQIEugsIwu4bcj8CBAgQ%2BFtgNGySomXU6s6TS3K94%2BK3BAgQOEVAEJ6yKfckQIBAuMBo5CSEy6jR3SeWYHrXxO8JECBwmoAgPG1j7kuAAIEwgVmR8%2BR4mWV092k92fSuhd8TIEDgVAFBeOrm3JsAAQIhArNi54nxMsvmnaf0RM93HPwZAgQInLI2VVQAABJKSURBVC4gCE%2FfoPsTIEDg4QKzo%2BcJITPb5O4TeoLh3Zn9ngABAk8VEIRP3ay5CBAg8BCBVfFzYtSssrj7VE60uzuj3xMgQCBFQBCmbNqcBAgQOFhgVQidEjar5n%2FnSZxi9s5s%2FgwBAgQSBQRh4tbNTIAAgcMEKoOoU%2FBUzn3lSXSyuXJfvyFAgACB1wKC8LWRXxAgQIBAA4HqONoVP9VzXlntLosrd%2FMbAgQIEBgTEIRjfv40AQIECBQJ7AilqhDaMduVtVXNf%2BUufkOAAAECawQE4RpXXyVAgACByQK7o2lmHO2e5dVqZs766iz%2FnQABAgT2CgjCvf5OJ0CAAIGLAl0i6t1Y6nL%2F33G%2FO9fF9fkZAQIECDQVEIRNF%2BNaBAgQIPBvge5BdfK%2BxODJ23N3AgQIjAkIwjE%2Ff5oAAQIEigQE4RpoMbjG1VcJECBwioAgPGVT7kmAAIFwAUE49wEIwbmevkaAAIFTBQThqZtzbwIECIQJCMLxhYvAcUNfIECAwNMEBOHTNmoeAgQIPFRAEL6%2FWCH4vp0%2FSYAAgacLCMKnb9h8BAgQeIiAILy%2FSCF438yfIECAQJqAIEzbuHkJECBwqIAgvL44IXjdyi8JECCQLiAI01%2BA%2BQkQIHCIgCC8tigxeM3JrwgQIEDgvwKC0EsgQIAAgSMEBOGf1yQEj3jGLkmAAIF2AoKw3UpciAABAgS%2BEhCE%2F68iAv1dIUCAAIFRAUE4KujPEyBAgECJwGgQfo%2Bn0e%2BUDPviECHYYQvuQIAAgWcICMJn7NEUBAgQeLzAaMh9FVGj36xEF4GV2s4iQIBAjoAgzNm1SQkQIHC0wGi8%2FSmoRr%2B9ClYErpL1XQIECBD4LiAIvQUCBAgQOEJgNNquxtXoOSOYV%2B84coY%2FS4AAAQIEfhYQhN4DAQIECBwhMBpqd2Nr9LyrqHfvdfW7fkeAAAECBK4ICMIrSn5DgAABAtsFRgPt3fAaPfdXuHfvsX0BLkCAAAECjxQQhI9cq6EIECDwPIHRMBNiz3sTJiJAgACBcQFBOG7oCwQIECBQICAIC5AdQYAAAQJxAoIwbuUGJkCAwJkCgvDMvbk1AQIECPQWEIS99%2BN2BAgQIPCPgCD0FAgQIECAwHwBQTjf1BcJECBAYIGAIFyA6pMECBAgEC8gCOOfAAACBAicISAIz9iTWxIgQIDAWQKC8Kx9uS0BAgRiBQRh7OoNToAAAQILBQThQlyfJkCAAIF5AoJwnqUvESBAgACB7wKC0FsgQIAAgSMEBOERa3JJAgQIEDhMQBAetjDXJUCAQKqAIEzdvLkJECBAYKWAIFyp69sECBAgME1AEE6j9CECBAgQIPBDQBB6DAQIECBwhIAgPGJNLkmAAAEChwkIwsMW5roECBBIFRCEqZs3NwECBAisFBCEK3V9mwABAgSmCQjCaZQ%2BRIAAAQIEfggIQo%2BBAAECBI4QEIRHrMklCRAgQOAwAUF42MJclwABAqkCgjB18%2BYmQIAAgZUCgnClrm8TIECAwDQBQTiN0ocIECBAgMAPAUHoMRAgQIDAEQKC8Ig1uSQBAgQIHCYgCA9bmOsSIEAgVUAQpm7e3AQIECCwUkAQrtT1bQIECBCYJiAIp1H6EAECBAgQ%2BCEgCD0GAgQIEDhCQBAesSaXJECAAIHDBAThYQtzXQIECKQKCMLUzZubAAECBFYKCMKVur5NgAABAtMEBOE0Sh8iQIAAAQI%2FBAShx0CAAAECRwgIwiPW5JIECBAgcJiAIDxsYa5LgACBVAFBmLp5cxMgQIDASgFBuFLXtwkQIEBgmoAgnEbpQwQIECBA4IeAIPQYCBAgQOAIAUF4xJpckgABAgQOExCEhy3MdQkQIJAqIAhTN29uAgQIEFgpIAhX6vo2AQIECEwRGI3Bz0t8fHxMuYuPECBAgACBJwkIwidt0ywECBB4qIAgfOhijUWAAAEC2wUE4fYVuAABAgQIvBIYDUL%2FOvhK2H8nQIAAgVQBQZi6eXMTIEDgIAFBeNCyXJUAAQIEjhIQhEety2UJECCQJzAag59i%2FoUw792YmAABAgSuCQjCa05%2BRYAAAQKbBAThJnjHEiBAgECEgCCMWLMhCRAgcK7AaBD618Fzd%2B%2FmBAgQILBeQBCuN3YCAQIECAwICMIBPH%2BUAAECBAi8EBCEnggBAgQItBUYjcHPwfwLYdv1uhgBAgQINBAQhA2W4AoECBAg8LWAIPQyCBAgQIDAWgFBuNbX1wkQIEBgQGA0CP3r4AC%2BP0qAAAECEQKCMGLNhiRAgMCZAoLwzL25NQECBAicIyAIz9mVmxIgQCBOQBDGrdzABAgQIFAsIAiLwR1HgAABAtcERmPw8xT%2FL6PXrP2KAAECBHIFBGHu7k1OgACB1gKCsPV6XI4AAQIEHiIgCB%2BySGMQIEDgaQKC8GkbNQ8BAgQIdBQQhB234k4ECBAg8E0QegQECBAgQGC9gCBcb%2BwEAgQIEHhDYDQI%2Fe8H30D3RwgQIEAgTkAQxq3cwAQIEDhDQBCesSe3JECAAIGzBQTh2ftzewIECDxWQBA%2BdrUGI0CAAIFGAoKw0TJchQABAgT%2BJyAIvQYCBAgQILBeQBCuN3YCAQIECEwWuBKL%2FjeEk9F9jgABAgQeKSAIH7lWQxEgQODZAoLw2fs1HQECBAjUCQjCOmsnESBAgMAkgVdB6F8HJ0H7DAECBAg8XkAQPn7FBiRAgMDzBATh83ZqIgIECBDYIyAI97g7lQABAgQGBP4UhP51cADWHyVAgACBOAFBGLdyAxMgQOB8AUF4%2Fg5NQIAAAQI9BARhjz24BQECBAjcEPgqCP3L4A1APyVAgAABAv8ICEJPgQABAgSOE%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%2B6jaetVJ6%2FbAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg%3D%3D
```

It is working fine when I run on django runserver, both on local and production environments.
However it gives me an 502 when running on production with NGINX.
So everything points out to NGINX.

This is the NGINX conf file, though I can't access the error logs (another programmer did the setup)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 5;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 6000;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}

http { 

        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##
        client_max_body_size 30M;
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 300;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    #timeout
    #proxy_read_timeout 1200;
    uwsgi_read_timeout 1200;
    client_body_timeout 120;
    client_header_timeout 120;
    send_timeout 100;
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    #client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

}

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Without a specific error there's not a whole hell of a lot we can do for you...

Comment: Check your nginx error log.

Comment: Please provide static_root, static_url, media_root settings, urls, views. 
Please provide your nginx log as well.

Also for static serve you can create  url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

Comment: Are you using gunicorn? If yes this could be the reason: http://serverfault.com/a/564468/158607

Comment: @ohrstrom Yes, spot on! that was the problem indeed. Though I couldn't change that because it's needed server security and performance I updated my function to an AJAX post instead of sending the the data through URL and that solved the issue. I'll post an answer with the combination of yours and this additional info.

Comment: OK :) beside that - is there a reason why you send the image encoded in the query string? Why not a `POST` request with the data in the body? Not sure - but there also could be issues with extremely long query strings with proxies or security appliances... (ah sorry - just noted that you did this...)

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by a comment by [ohrstrom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/469111/ohrstrom), who linked to this answer:
https://serverfault.com/questions/564464/nginx-request-line-too-large/564468#564468

These parameters:

```
client_header_buffer_size 1k;
large_client_header_buffers 4 32k;
```

Were blocking the call.

Aside from that it was a VERY bad idea on my side sending such a large amount of data in the url. I ended up using a POST with the base64 data on the body and that solved the problem.